# Reference in R.java not final

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

When generating the reference for a stylable attribute there seems to be something going wrong in the generation of the R.java file.

One would expect the declaration of the field to be `final` but it is not. How come?

res/values/attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyTextView">
        <attr name="typeface" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

gen/com.example/R.java

```
    /**
      <p>This symbol is the offset where the {@link com.example.R.attr#typeface}
      attribute's value can be found in the {@link #MyTextView} array.
      <p>Must be a string value, using '\\;' to escape characters such as '\\n' or '\\uxxxx' for a unicode character.
      <p>This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "<code>@[<i>package</i>: <i>type</i>:<i>name</i></code>") or theme attribute (in the form "<code>?[<i>package</i>: [<i>type</i>:]<i>name</i></code>") containing a value of this type. 
       @attr name com.example:typeface
    */
    public static int MyTextView_typeface = 0;
```

Comment: How `R.java` is generated (and why) is some internal I don't think someone here can answer

Comment: Checkout updated jucas' answer. It's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References inside R.java are not final since a couple of years ago.

The reason for this is that the ids generated might clash if you had several library projects that your main project depends on.

Here is more explanation on this: http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

Comment: Thank you! The issue occurred after we moved code into a library so it all makes sense now.